# {filename} is outputting the extension as well

Tags: assets

I am on EE 2.5.5 and Assets 2.1.3.

`{cf_moebel_assets}` is a custom assets field.  The `{filename}` variable outputs the extension as well:

```
{cf_moebel_assets}
    {subfolder}{filename}-z1.{extension}
{/cf_moebel_assets}
```

this will render as:

```
designklassiker_tisch.jpg-z1.jpg
```

I've tried it on a standalone template and the short version. It always outputs the extension.

Comment: Hi outline 4 - I'm going to report this as a bug.  I'll keep you updated with the fix.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Lisa, and yes a hotfix would be very nice, since I need to move forward with the project. cheers

Comment: bumpedibump.... is there a fix available?? I am blocked since over a week...

Comment: Sorry outline4!  You'll need to follow up by email for an update on this. :)  support@pixelandtonic.com....